# What certificates does 'curl' use by default?

Tags: curl, certificate

What certificates does 'curl' use by default?

Example:

```
curl -I -L https://cruises.webjet.com.au
```

fails on Ubuntu 15.04 with

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But when I add the root certificate (see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cruises.webjet.com.au&latest) and run

```
curl -I -L --cacert downlaodedCert.pem https://cruises.webjet.com.au
```

everything is fine. So I guess 'curl' doesn't use this root certificate by default.

But how can I see which certs it uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

curl uses its own bundle of ca certificates.

So normally you need to add trusted server, one way of doing so is the way you did. Another way if you for example are using Firefox is [certutil](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

> You can also extract the ca certs off your Firefox installation, if
>   you just have the 'certutil' tool installed and run the
>   [firefox-db2pem.sh](http://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/firefox-db2pem.sh) script!

Hope you find this information helpful :)

Note: The script is a shell script, so if you are on windows it will be a bit more complicated to use. Might still be possible using msys or cygwin. But by then it starting to become more work than it probably is worth.